# Alarm fireing too early

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an alarm for notification.

The problem I'm facing is that it's firing the notification too early...

I really need to get the date and time from date and time picker.

I have no clue whats wrong with my code. Here's is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fire = findViewById(R.id.fire);
        choose = findViewById(R.id.choose);

        choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Calendar cal = getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(DAY_OF_MONTH);

                final DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light,
                        mDataSetListener,
                        year,month,day
                );

                dialog.setOnDateSetListener(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, final int year, final int day, final int month) {
                        final Calendar calTime = getInstance();
                        int hour = calTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        int minute = calTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                        final String datum = day + "." + month + "." + year;

                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {

                                final Calendar cal_new = getInstance();
                                cal_new.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                                cal_new.set(Calendar.MONTH,month-1);
                                cal_new.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,day);

                                cal_new.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hour);
                                cal_new.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);


                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,day + " " + month + " " + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                                Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Alarm.class);
                                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,in,0);
                                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal_new.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
                            }
                        },hour,minute,true);
                        timePickerDialog.show();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();

            }
        });
```

**Alarm.java** (BroadCastReceiver)

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Yeah", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        try {
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
            r.play();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried some solutions but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you setting month-1 to the alarm manager? what dates are you trying? Could you be more specific about how early is being fired?

Comment: At calendar month starts with 0 so january is not 1 it is 0, thats why.

I make an note app and this app should provide remember notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `month-1` expecting to get values from 1 to 12. The `month` at onDateChanged already are 0 to 11 for compatibility with Calendar.

There is no need to modify the month you get, set it to the alarm manager like this:

```
cal_new.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
```

Check [DatePickerDiaglo doc.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#onDateChanged(android.widget.DatePicker,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: I've made month-1 to get 0 to 11, when I make an Toast it shows me the right date.

Comment: check the link to the doc please and take a look at the description of the month.

Comment: I don't get what you mean ._.

Comment: just edited the answer with the line you need to change

Comment: When I remove the -1 there is now the wrong date (December) and there is absolutly no notification

Comment: what date are you choosing?

Comment: Oh my god, Month was day and day was month. I changd the name of the parameters ad onTimeSet.... urgh ... sometimes its so silly...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your `cal_new` might be getting initialized with `hour` and `minute` variables from outside `onTimeSet()`. Try renaming the parameters.

Comment: Nope, didn't changed something :(